# Search engines for Hierarchy Tree

Tags: mongodb, solr, neo4j, lucene, search-engine

We are working on a proposal to find a suitable search engine for our requirement. Let me explain our data structure. It is a hierarchy data structure. Basically a product details arranged in a tree like the below.

**Hierarchy Structure**

Bakery

Breads

Biscuits

Bread Sticks

Bun & Rolls

Coffee-Shops

Rolyalty

Bevarage

Pakaged Food

There is a search requirement coming up for the above tree structure. We are kind of exploring various tools.

We have tried with the Nested set model in mysql database. So the above tree is being constructed as a nested set model with the left,right positions. Since the concurrent number of requests are more and considering the scalability we moved more in terms of in-memory/search engines which would handle the request faster.

So we have started exploring Apache Solr built on lucene. We understand that solr is more suitable for flat structure search rather than hierarchy node search. But we tried creating the tree as a flat structure but we ended up in the below complication.

**Flat structure**
 L1                   L2                L3
Bakery             Breads         Biscuits
Bakery             Breads         Bread Sticks
Bakery             Breads         Bun & Rolls
Coffee-Shops       Rolyalty       Bevarage
Coffee-Shops       Rolyalty       Pakaged Food

**Issue in flat structure**
We created this structure in Solr and while we do the search across all levels with "Bakery", we end up in getting the below three records

Bakery   Breads   Biscuits
Bakery   Breads   Bread Sticks
Bakery   Breads   Bun & Rolls

**Our requirement**
Our requirement is to send only the match node and its parent. While we are working with the cross reference then only one node will be one which needs to be sent that is Bakery...

In our case there is going to be huge volumes of records and we feel this flat structure might not be right option.

Can you please suggest any good options to approach the above mentioned search. ideally the response should be also a tree...is it like persisting a tree and we will be able to search based on the node and also fetch its parents Neo4j?. rather we processing the search results. the volumes of data would be around 20 million

Answer (score 1):

I think that this MongoDB official document has your answer, which you have to choose based on your usage patterns:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/data-models-tree-structures/

Comment: Thanks Tiramisu. Had a look at this. Since we have more complex requirements in search, we would like to leverage the search capabilities provided by search engine.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from Solr 6, there is a support for [basic graph traversal](http://www.slideshare.net/KevinWatters2/solr-60-graph-query-overview). This would allow you to structure flat documents for discoverability and graph traversal for parent inclusion in the results.

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. i think this will help. We might have to define the structure in a vertical fashion and then have the parent references to it.

Example if we have the structure like this

Node &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Parent
Bakery
Breads
Bread Sticks

Comment: The adjancy model is defined here - http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/

pls correct if my understanding is not correct

Comment: So if I structured the data with this adjacency model then I can use the graph query parser with solr  I believe